# ERROR { MongoError: Unknown modifier: $pushAll when updating with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am converting an AngularJS app to Angular 7, and they share a backend API.  I am submitting the same data, and it logs correctly, but when trying to save the record I get an error returned on the backend about unknown modifier $pushAll.

My controller code:

```
    Volunteer
    .findById(volunteerId)
    .select('shifts')
    .exec(function(err, volunteer) {
      var thisShift;
      var response = {
        status : 200,
        message : {}
      };
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error finding volunteer request");
        response.status = 500;
        response.message = err;
      } else if(!volunteer) {
        console.log("Volunteer request not found", volunteerId);
        response.status = 404;
        response.message = {
          "message" : "Volunteer request not found " + volunteerId
        };
      } else {
        // Get the shift
        thisShift = volunteer.shifts.id(shiftId);
        console.log("SHIFT BEFORE UPDATE", JSON.stringify(thisShift));
        // If the shift doesn't exist Mongoose returns null
        if (!thisShift) {
          response.status = 404;
          response.message = {
            "message" : "Shift not found " + shiftId
          };
        }
      }
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        res
          .status(response.status)
          .json(response.message);
      } else {
        thisShift.volleyteers.push({
          fullname: user.name,
          phone: user.phone,
          email: user.username
        });
        console.log("thisShift to be saved", JSON.stringify(thisShift));
        volunteer.save(function(err, volunteerUpdated) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR",err);
            res
              .status(500)
              .json(err);
          } else {
            console.log("SUCCESS!");
            res
              .status(204)
              .json({message: "Thank you for volunteering!  You can see where you need to on your profile page or someone will contact you."});
          }
        });
      }
    });
};
```

The error I get, along with the console.logged stuff on the backend is:
[image: My console.logged data and error]

I'm using:

- Node 11.13.0
- MongoDB server version: 4.0.8
- "mongoose": "^4.9.6"

How do I get this error to go away so I can save the updated record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [issue comes to mind](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5574#issuecomment-332290518). `$pullAll` is deprecated in MongoDB but it is utilized behind the scenes by mongoose.

The workaround seems to be adding `usePushEach: true` to schemas until version 5.0.0-rc2 as per [this](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4455).

This piece of code seems to be the cause of it:

```
thisShift.volleyteers.push({
   fullname: user.name,
   phone: user.phone,
   email: user.username
});
```

Since you are asking mongoose to save an array of objects.

Another workaround for mongoose not to utilize behind the scenes `$pushAll` seems to be to try to use concat:

```
thisShift.volleyteers.concat([{
   fullname: user.name,
   phone: user.phone,
   email: user.username
}]);
```

As [specified here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4455#issuecomment-250404913)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue. The problem is the $pushall function was deprecated but some old version of Mongoose still use it. I upgraded Mongoose to version 5.6.11 ( the latest one), the issue is gone.

P/S: If you use mongoose-unique-validator plugin, you should upgrade it too (I upgraded to version 2.0.3)

Hope it helps